# error with cross referenced foreign key constraints

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I had a weird problem when I am trying to create tables in MySQL.

I want to have a cross reference two many-to-many tables and here is the code I create table

```
create table teacher(
t_id char(10) not null unique, 
name varchar(20) not null, 
sur_name varchar(20) not null, 
CONSTRAINT pk_teacher PRIMARY KEY(t_id))

create table student(
s_id char(10) not null unique,
name varchar(20) not null,
sur_name varchar(20) not null,
CONSTRAINT pk_student PRIMARY KEY(s_id))

create table teacher_student(
t_id char(10) not null,
s_id char(10) not null,
CONSTRAINT pk_teacher_student PRIMARY KEY(t_id, s_id))
```

in order to add foreign constraints I used the following code

```
ALTER TABLE teacher_student 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_teacher_student FOREIGN KEY(s_id) REFERENCES student(s_id)
ALTER TABLE teacher_student 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_student_teacher FOREIGN KEY(t_id) REFERENCES teacher(t_id)
ALTER TABLE student 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_student_teacher_student 
FOREIGN KEY(s_id) REFERENCES teacher_student(s_id)
ALTER TABLE teacher 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_teacher_teacher_student
FOREIGN KEY(t_id) REFERENCES teacher_student(t_id)
```

that works fine but if I try to execute code in a different order like this

```
ALTER TABLE student 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_student_teacher_student 
FOREIGN KEY(s_id) REFERENCES teacher_student(s_id)
ALTER TABLE teacher 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_teacher_teacher_student
FOREIGN KEY(t_id) REFERENCES teacher_student(t_id)
ALTER TABLE teacher_student 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_teacher_student FOREIGN KEY(s_id) REFERENCES student(s_id)
ALTER TABLE teacher_student 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_student_teacher FOREIGN KEY(t_id) REFERENCES teacher(t_id)
ALTER TABLE student
```

I am getting exception

```
Can't create table 'test.#sql-44c_37' (errno: 150)
```

My question is, why the order is important? what is the difference between these two ways of creating constraints? thanks

Answer (score 0):

"I try to execute code in a different order like this" You have no different order you have extremely different constraints. You can't create such constraints.
Examine this article for more information

[**FOREIGN KEY Constraints**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Answer (score 0):

Some of your foreign keys don't seem to make any sense.

Those referencing `student` and `teacher` (the `fk_teacher_student` and `fk_student_teacher` ones) are fine. That's actually a typical case of a many-to-many table referencing each of the two entity tables whose many-to-many relationship is being implemented.

Now, what are you proposing with referencing back from those tables to the many-to-many one? I admit that I can't really explain why the foreign keys were successfully added using the first script and failed with the other. Sorry about that. Even though I've got some vague idea, that's not really the point of my answer. The point is, your present design is going to make it difficult for you to add new data. With it, you can't really add, say, a student without adding also a relationship between the new student and an existing teacher. This is because a row in `student` is supposed to reference an existing student in `teacher_student`, but since it is a new student, there's no corresponding row in `teacher_student` yet. Same goes for a new teacher.

So, consider just abandoning the idea of `fk_student_teacher_student` and `fk_teacher_teacher_student`. They are not needed to your design. They have already caused you to solve an unnecessary problem and they are likely to cause more trouble in the future.